# Module options in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I'd like to write something like behaviors in Yii2, so I need not only module but also options to define how it works.

Example what I need:

```
class User
    include FullNameModule
    show_full_lastname false
    ...
end
```

I saw such case in Paperclip gem:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

What I have for now:

```
module FullNameModule
  def full_name
    if show_full_lastname
      "#@name #@last_name"
    else
      "#@name #{@last_name[0]}."
    end
  end

  def self.included klass
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end


  def show_full_lastname
    self.class.instance_variable_get('@show_full_lastname')
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def show_full_lastname b
      @show_full_lastname = b
    end
  end
end

class User
    include FullNameModule
    show_full_lastname false

    def initialize params
      @name = params[:name]
      @last_name = params[:last_name]
    end
end


user = User.new ({name: 'John', last_name: 'Tailor'})
p user.full_name
```

It works fine, but looks ugly a little, what is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing "Class Methods" inside of a module? You should write a separate Class for Class Methods and write it so that the module can be included inside of the Class and then have the Class User inherit from that Class. I'm not really understanding the purpose of this

```
def self.included klass
 klass.extend ClassMethods
end
```

either. Modules are to be used inside of Multiple Classes, while Classes are meant for Single Inheritance. You actually don't even need a "ClassMethods" to handles this. Here is a better way;

--- Edit ----

Actually, you made this WAY more complicated than it needed to be. After a 30 minute session of messing around with the code, this is what I come up with.

```
module FullNameModule
 def name(b)
    if b == true
        return "#@name #@last_name"
    else
        return "#{@name} #{@last_name[0]}."
    end
  end
end

class User
 include FullNameModule

 def initialize params
  @name = params[:name]
  @last_name = params[:last_name]
 end
end


user = User.new ({name: 'John', last_name: 'Tailor'})
p user.name(false)
```

Comment: I see what are u talking about, but what if I want to set option in class definition, like a Paperclip gem? I updated the answer.

Comment: About "klass.extend ClassMethods" - I've read it from here http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/

Comment: The option is set up, it is a true or false method. You could set it up in the class but it's always good practice to keep reusable code inside of modules and not Classes. Classes are for Objects, Modules are for Methods.